# Is it possible to find all discussion posts by a specific user on Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have a list of user names. IS it possible to use Wikipedia's API to query for a user's posts?

Comment: Just to clarify: You are looking for everything that user wrote on any discussion page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By “discussion posts”, I assume that you mean edits on discussion pages. You can get all user contributions for a specific user, or a list of users from the API, using [`usercontribs`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aUsercontribs):

```
https://sv.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=usercontribs&ucuser=Rotsee|User2|User3
```

To get discussion posts, you want to limit your results to discussion pages. These are in separate namespaces, one discussion namespace for each ordinary namespace. The discussion namespace is normally numbered namespace+1, starting from 1 (main namespace discussion), etc.

This would return the latest posts on discussion pages of ordinary page at Swedish Wikipedia, for the three users Rotsee, User1 and User2:

```
    https://sv.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=usercontribs&ucuser=Rotsee|User2|User3&ucnamespace=1&ucdir=older
```

The deafult discussion namespaces [are](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aNamespace):

```
Talk          1
User talk     3
Project talk  5
File talk     7
MediaWiki talk 9
Template talk 11
Help talk     13
Category talk 15
```

This is the default MediaWiki setup. On Wikimedia sites there are [a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aNamespace) of other namespaces, added by various extensions, as pointed out by @svick below.

Comment: Actually, [Wikipedia has several other namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Namespace), e.g. Module, Portal and Book.